# How to get photos with smart previews out of Lightroom if the original photos cannot be located?

Tags: lightroom, file-recovery

How can I get photos out of Adobe Lightroom Classic CC if the original photos cannot be located, such as if the drive containing them is broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some circumstances, exporting the image will work. The exported image will usually be lower-quality than the original, as this is how smart previews are stored by Lightroom.

However, sometimes, the images will not be exportable even with a smart preview. In these situations, you should go find your smart previews.

**Note**: This will only work if you still have the folder containing your Lightroom catalog files.

#### Where Smart Previews are Stored

The smart previews are stored in the `Lightroom Catalog Smart Previews.lrdata` folder in your Lightroom catalog folder. For more information on where Lightroom catalog folders are stored, please visit [this Adobe FAQ](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/kb/catalog-faq-lightroom.html#Wherearemyimagesandcataloglocated).

Inside the folder, there are other folders, from 0—F. Inside *those* folders are even more folders. Inside these deep folders are the Lightroom smart previews. These smart previews are stored as DNG files. These DNG files are lower resolution and are *smaller* (both in file size and in pixel dimension size). On a PC, DNG files can be opened by Microsoft Photos, although by default, they will open in Snip & Sketch.